# Prove the Cauchy Schwarz equality using vector dot product.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Prove the Cauchy Schwarz inequality using vector dot product.
I can't seem to make any progress on it.
To prove this inequality;
$(a_1b_1+....a_nb_n)^2<(a_1^2+....a_n^2)(b_1^2+....b_n^2)$

Comment: Write down explicitly what "equality" you need and what you did try.

Comment: Examine the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial
$$
p(t) = ( x + t y) \cdot (x + t y)
$$
and note that, by construction, $p(t) \geq 0$.  Here $x$ and $y$ are vectors, and $t$ is a scalar.

Comment: I think that [this proof](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/417/CauchySchwartz.pdf) is very interesting too. In other words it is the rearranging of $0\le (|u|v-|v|u)^2$

Answer (score 5):

Consider $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then we have

$$0\le (\alpha u+v)\cdot(\alpha u+v)=\alpha^2 |u|^2+2\alpha u\cdot v+|v|^2.$$ This is a polynomial of degree $2$ in $\alpha.$ It can't have two different roots (why?). So its discriminant must be nonpositive. That is $$4(u\cdot v)^2-4|u|^2|v|^2\le 0.$$ Take square roots and you are done.

Comment: +1 for simplicity... this approach seems a lot easier than what I knew.

Comment: if it can only be greater or equal to zero, then wont its discriminant be nonposotive? As it can only be zero and have one root?

Comment: @grigori Thank you so much for noticing the mistake. You are completely right.

Comment: no worries and what about the general case though?

Comment: @grigori What do you mean for the general case?

Comment: sorry I think ive explained it bad in the description... ive edited it now... to prove that inequality in my description, yours proves it for a1,a2,b1,b2

Comment: @grigori The polynomial is in $\alpha$ wich is a scalar. The proof works in any dimensions. Just write $u=(a_1,\cdots,a_n), v=(b_1,\cdots, b_n).$ If you prefer to write the proof writing explicitly the coordinates of $u$ and $v$ it works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: observe that

$$0\le (x- \alpha y|x-\alpha y)=(x|x)+(\alpha y|\alpha y)- 2\Re (x|\alpha y)=(x|x)+|\alpha|^2(y|y)-2\Re(\bar\alpha(x|y))$$

by the properties of any dot product, for vectors $x,y$ and scalar $\alpha$. Now set $\alpha:=\frac{(x|y)}{(y|y)}$ and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

$$|v\cdot w|=|\|v\|\|w\|\cos(\theta)|\leq \|v\|\|w\|$$

Comment: Not sure if the OP wanted this proof for the general case (possibly of dimension higher than $3$).

Comment: yes I was thinking along these lines as for example if you have ax, ay, az as the x.y and z component, then the product  of magniutes of the vectors is greater than or equal to the product of the x y and z components? But yes I guess it will get really complex when looking at 4 dimensions ect...